# Facebook can not create a application

Tags: facebook

I want to build a facebook app. I create a new application, put all information, like app domain, site url. Then click i to save, and error comes up:

Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.

[image: facebook error]

Where is a problem? Couple days ago, i can create a other app with no problems.

Update: If i want to make some changes on other applications on app settings tab, also click save and this error comes up.

Comment: what is that error???

Comment: this is facebook... try again in an hour or so

Comment: may be they are facing some intermittent issues. try after sometime.

Comment: There is nothing the users of [so] can do to help you with this. If the problem persists, you should report this to Facebook.

Comment: I have exact same problem,atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here the progress on fixing the bug: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/629640800428208/

edit: it's working for me now. ( 2014.01.08 19:10 GMT+1 )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about it. They must be working on something. So they must have disabled the functionality for the time being.

Comment: Ok, check it for latter.

Comment: Hmmm.. That sounds good.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should have been a comment.

Comment: OK may be it should be in comment section. @lix can you provide the answer, I am eager to upvote you.

Comment: @FurquanKhan - there is no answer. The error message contains all the information that is available. Facebook makes updates all the time, their motto is "move fast and break stuff". This seems like one of those cases. As I said in a comment on the question, if the problem persists, a report should be made to Facebook.

Comment: Someone can simply test it, create a demo app and see, if this problem exist for other users, people? Thanks.

Comment: @Foxsk8 - That doesn't take in to consideration the users locations. Depending on where they are they are most likely communicating with totally different servers. I **am** able to create new applications but that is not an indication of anything.